# What is the workflow when using git,maven,puppet and jenkins?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, puppet

I have a maven project which uses git for version control. I have setup jenkins to perform maven builds for specific revisions of my repo. What i have thought is, I can use puppet to deploy specific builds done by jenkins.

Is there any other workflow which i can try, when using git,maven,puppet and jenkins?

Comment: There's "Validated Merge" plugin in Jenkins Enterprise (commercial) that allows you to commit "to Jenkins" (which runs a Git repository itself), builds your changes, and, if successful, commits to the actual repository. Skips puppet though.

Answer (score 1):

Currently we a have a "per feature" branch [flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

I've setup jenkins with several jobs

- `my_project-ci` : one that poll the git server and do continuous integrations on all branch starting with `origin/feature/*`
- then we a have a build [pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)

  - `my_project` : launch test, once the something is merged in master, it then [archive](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin) the workspace and trigger the following job
  - `my_project-staging` : this one deploy automatically to the stating servers
  - `my_project-production` : this one is triggered manual

the cycle looks like :

- *local* : Clone -> git branch -b feature/super-feature -> commit -> local build -> git push
- **jenkins** : Jenkins cron for origin/feature/*
- **local other dev** : review the feature via pull request
- *local* : fix -> commit -> local build -> push
- **local other dev** : merge the pullrequest in master
- **jenkins** : Jenkins cron origin/master
- **jenkins** : trigger my_project-staging
- *local* : validate deployment and trigger manually the my_project-production
- **jenkins** : deploy to production

I'm not a big fan of using puppet for deployment, it works great for provisionning but it handles badly orchestration of deployments (eg run db migration, in a cluster, remove one member from load balancer, deploy, re-add to balancer). Take a look a tools like [ansible](http://arrfab.net/blog/?p=410), capistrano,...

Answer (score 0):

Well all tools you have described are orthogonal to each other.

typical workflow is

Clone -> commit -> local build -> push -> Jenkins cron -> deply